# infinity sum of numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we have a series of numbers $$1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + \cdots + (10^n)^5.$$ Final sum of the series is approximately equal $16666\ldots$ .

If there is more and more numbers in the series is the result of closer and closer to $16666\ldots$ .

For example if the last number $1000$ or $10000$ or $100000$ and so on, the final sum is closer to $16666\ldots$ . If it is true (of course it is), can we conclude that $$1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + \cdots = \frac 1 6$$

Greetings.

Comment: What is Srbin (pozdrav)?

Comment: @Peter:  I suspect that as well, but I'm trying to give the poster the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Pozdrav means "greetings" in Czech, and "srbin" means "a Serb".

Comment: If you're just interested in how the number $1^5 + 2^5 + \cdots (10^n)^5$ begins in base $10$, then it may make more sense to investigate $(1^5 + 2^5 + \cdots + (10^n)^5)/10^{5n}$ (or something).

Comment: Marko, your observation follows from a general fact $$1^m+2^m+\cdots+n^m \approx \frac{1}{m+1}n^{m+1}.$$

Comment: It still makes no sense that the sum of positive numbers larger than $1/6$ can be $1/6$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I think there is some regularization going on. Maybe of if the OP explained.

Comment: what the heck is this OP I am seeing of late in all the comments?

Comment: @ajay "OP" is an abbreviation for "original poster". In this case the original poster is marko.

Comment: @MJD thanks for enlightening me :) I am still wondering if this question makes any sense at all.

Comment: @ajay It turns out that [a search for "OP" on Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=OP) produces [What does "OP" mean?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/what-does-op-mean) as the #1 hit. This suggests a strategy that might be useful if you become similarly puzzled in the future.

Answer (score 7):

The orthogonal projection of this question onto the subspace of sensible questions is answered by @sos440's comment.

> Claim: $$\frac{1^m + 2^m + \cdots + n^m}{n^{m+1}}\to \frac{1}{m+1}.$$

Proof: Note $\text{LHS} = \frac{1}{n}((1/n)^m + (2/n)^m + \cdots + ((n-1)/n)^m + 1^m)$ is a Riemann sum approximating the integral $\int_0^1 x^m\,dx = \frac{1}{m+1}$.

Thus we can say that $$1^5 + 2^5 + \cdots + (10^n)^5 \sim \frac{1}{6} (10^n)^6,$$which will look like $1666\ldots$ in base $10$, as you correctly observe.

Comment: I upvoted this as soon as I read the first sentence, but on later perusal, the rest of the answer was pretty good too.